# Best known results on the flexible jobshop benchmarks

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, scheduling, or-tools, cp-sat

Is there a website that compiles the best known results on the **flexible jobshop** problem ?

I know there was a blog post/article by *Quintiq*, a (deleted) blog post on *CP Optimizer*, some more recent articles, but nothing easy to read.

I have some good results with *OR-Tools CP-SAT*, but it is hard to judge exactly their quality.

Comment: Would you see this [link](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3790/scheduling-problem-data-generation/3795#3795)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. It gives me more datasets. But I am trying to find the best results on the Brandimarte, the Dauziere, the Huring data sets among others.

Comment: Hurink data set.

Answer (score 2):

The recent FJSP overview paper by [Dauzère-Pérès et al. (2024)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037722172300382X) has a list of best-known solutions for classical FJSP instances in their supplementary materials. However, they did not include results from the new FJSP instances of [Naderi and Roshanaei (2022)](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/ijoo.2021.0056). The latter also includes results from CP Optimizer on classic FJSP benchmark instances, which may also be of interest to you :-)

Comment: Thank you so much!